# Blender 2.82 - Objects are not visible in solid/wireframe shading

Tags: 3d-view

suddenly I have this problem. In the main window in 3D Viewport all objects (excl. ref images) are not visible while viewport shading is solid or wireframe, even the outlines. In material or rendered is everything as it should be.
In my secondary window it's ok and I can see them. When I select an object in the second window I can transform it in the main window. I just don't see it there, only in the main window. And in the main window is this weird "shadow" wich is formed like a pyramid. The settings for the viewport (at least the screenshots below) are the same for both windows.
Does someone know where I can switch that off?

I use Blender 2.82

[image]
[image] main window

[image] second window

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The screenshot are too small and there is no setting visible. I would check visibility settings first

Comment: thanks,
the Screen shots with the complete screens should show the pyramid formed shadow.
Your are right the with the settings but they are the same in both windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but I found it by accident. I had the same problems and suspected it might be something to to with clipping. So I tried this and it worked. In the 3d viewport there are some menues. Click on the view menu ..

[image]

Choose "View Regions" and then choose "Clipping Region"

Voila!